# how post a file via curl function in php?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

i want to write a script which post a form automatically.
it is not a spammer!
there is a picture field in form.
i want to write the script with php and using curl() function.
how can i implement file uploading?
and is the php suitable for this purpose? i mean form posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload a file that's on your server, yes, curl can do the trick.

You'll want to use the **`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`** option, passing it to the [**`curl_setopt`**](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt) function *(quoting)* :

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST"
> operation. 
> **To post a file,
> prepend a filename with `@` and use
> the full path.**

Not tested, but I suppose that something like this should work :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.yoursite.com/destination-of-upload.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setpopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'file' => '@/..../some-file.txt',    // you'll need to adapt this
        // some other fields ?
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```