# my php curl upload dosn't work, display nothing?

Tags: php, curl

i'm trying to test my server, and to do that,
i make a robot to upload one file (in future, i'll make it repeatedly)...

but, the upload file did not send...

here the curl

```
<?php
$postdata = array();
$postdata ['fieldname'] = "@/home/egy/Downloads/BIO11_0201001D.DBF";  //fieldname should be same as file input box name

$post_url = 'form-handler.php'; //url to upload file

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);


echo $response;
?>
```

and this is the handler:

```
<?php

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fieldname']['tmp_name'], "upload"))
{
    echo "success";
}

?>
```

in my php, i set `display_error = on` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`

my DBF never send to server, but there is no error or warning....
am i doing wrong?

NB: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely becuase you need to use `$_FILES['fieldname']['name']` to get what the name was in the file input box named `fieldname`

Comment: hahaha,.. my mistake... it because my php handler is wrong, i forgot how to store file with `move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you had an enctype in your form. Mistake a lot of people make, including my self.

`<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to upload a file local to the box the script is running from.. see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624099/how-post-a-file-via-curl-function-in-php)